# Fetch maximum number of columns for a specific set of rows

Tags: c#, .net, excel, visual-studio

If I want to fetch the max number of columns for a set of rows in Excel, using Visual Studio, how would this be done?

Here is my current attempt which yields the maximum number of columns across the whole sheet instead of the specified rows. here are my attempts at this. All the necessary stuff such as using, initialize an Excel project etc are there, but not shown here.

```
class Sheets
{
    public Excel.Application app;  //= new Excel.Application();
    public Excel.Workbook book;    //
    public Excel._Worksheet sheet; //= book.Sheets["XML Inputs"];
    public Excel.Range range;      // = sheet.UsedRange;

    public Sheets()
    {
        app = new Excel.Application();
        book = app.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\dev\Development\Joseph\Projects\PTAC XML File\PTAC XML File\Excel Read FIle 3.0.xlsx");
        sheet = book.Sheets["XML Inputs"];
        range = sheet.UsedRange;

        int rowcount = range.Rows.Count;
        int columncount = range.Columns.Count;

        int i = 0;

    }

    public void Output()
    {

        Excel.Range fastrange1 = (Excel.Range)sheet.Cells[12, 1]; //fetch the number of columns for row 12


        for (int i = 12; i == 12; i++)                            //given row 12, count the number of coulmns
        {

            int fastrange = range.Columns.Count;
            Console.WriteLine(fastrange);
        }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
```

But be aware this could return more than you expect depending on the edit history of the sheet. Meaning that say the user entered data up to column Z, the sheet is saved, then the data (not the column) in Z is deleted, it could be still considered part of the UsedRange until such time as the entire column is deleted. Here is an example where we used it in a PowerShell script (should be the same in .net) to compress the sheet (clean up instances like I described). It's not the most efficient code, but it works.

```
# attach to excel object
$objExcel = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");

$book = $objExcel.ActiveWorkbook
$shtCount = $book.Sheets.Count
Write-Host $shtCount

for($i = 1; $i -le $shtCount; $i++){
    $sht = $book.Worksheets.item($i)
    $sht.Activate();
    $sht.UsedRange.Select();
    $rows = $sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
    $columns = $sht.UsedRange.Columns.Count;
    Write-Host $sht.UsedRange.Address();
    Write-Host "Rows: $rows"
    Write-Host "Columns: $columns"
    #remove blank columns
    for($c = $columns; $c -ge 1; $c--){
        $hasData = 0;
        for($r = 1; $r -le $rows; $r++){
            $cell = $sht.Cells.Item($r, $c);
            if($cell.Text -ne ""){ 
                $hasData = 1;
                break; 
            }
        }
        if($hasData){ 
            Write-Host "Column $c Has Data";
        } else{
            Write-Host "Column $c Has No Data";
            $cell.EntireColumn.Delete();
        }
    }#end for columns
    #remove blank rows
    for($r = $rows; $r -ge 1; $r--){
        $hasData = 0;
        for($c = 1; $c -le $columns; $c++){
            $cell = $sht.Cells.Item($r, $c);
            if($cell.Text -ne ""){ 
                $hasData = 1;
                break; 
            }
        }
        if($hasData){ 
            Write-Host "Row $r Has Data";
        } else{
            Write-Host "Row $r Has No Data";
            $cell.EntireRow.Delete();
        }
    }#end for rows
}#end for sheets

#clean up com objects
[void][System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::FinalReleaseComObject($cell)
[void][System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::FinalReleaseComObject($sht)
[void][System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::FinalReleaseComObject($book)
[void][System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::FinalReleaseComObject($objExcel)
```

EDIT: based on the comments, here is some ugly code:

```
int maxCol = 0;
int columns = sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count;
Range fastRange = sheet.get_Range("R12C1", "R12C" + columns); //Gets row 12 to used Range
foreach(Range r in fastRange){
    if(!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Text)) && r.Column > maxCol) maxCol = r.Column;
}
Console.WriteLine("Max column for row 12 is: " + maxCol);
```

I'm doing this off the top of my head, I think the method calls are valid. You can use the RxCx row column naming format to get a cell. If you wanted to get a single cell use `get_Range("R12C3", Type.Missing)`. hopefully the above gets you started. The test for a used cell is up to you (could be lots of options).

Comment: It would be a lot different in .NET/C#, however I think your suggestion on Range.Columns.Count was good.

Comment: wouldn't that count the max number of columns across the whole sheet? for example, if in rows 5-10, there are 4 used columns. For rows 11-15, there are 8 used columns. the result would yield 8. how would i fetch the number of columns used in rows 5-10?

Comment: Clay, I have written for .NET/C#, and PowerShell. It surprising how similar it is in the end. For PowerShell and .NET the method names on the objects are mostly the same.

Comment: JW, you have to define 'used'. If a sheet consists of 30 columns, then as far as Excel is concerned, all those columns are technically used. However, from our perspective they may not be used if a column contains no data (every cell is blank). The only way to tell would be to iterate over the range and see if a cell returns a value. But even though a cell is blank, it could still contain a formula. So it would be up to the programmer to decide what makes a cell 'unused'

Comment: i have used.range in my code already (just not pictured above). i need to link columns and rows rather than know all the rows and columns of a sheet

Comment: jw, when you say link, are you trying to get a range of cells (just as if you highlighted them manually in Excel) say from  A10 to and including D15: so that you and up with a range containing 24 cells?

Comment: i am hoping to look at a set of rows, e.x. rows 5-10. then find the number of columns used in those rows. so rows 5-10 use 6 columns. a different set of rows, rows 11-15, use 8 columns.

Comment: jw, got it. maybe edit your question at the top with that information as most of your code is correct, but your loop is not. You need to get a Range containing the cells from rows 5-10 for the columns in the UsedRange, Iterate over those cell and find the max of the column for used cells in that range, Get a new Range 11-15 for columns in the UsedRange and repeat the process displaying or saving the max used column for each range group.

Comment: im not entirely sure how that would look. what i have above is how i thought it would be done. could you demonstrate what you mean by any chance? note: since rows 8-12 had the same number of columns, i was just looking at row 12 thats why the loop looks like that.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use a NuGet package called EPPlus. The first step would be to locate your excel document and then cycle through the columns and rows...

```
//Get file path
var excelFile = new FileInfo("your-path-here");

//Open file using epplus
using(var package = new ExcelPackage(excelFile))
{
    ExcelWorkbook wkbk = package.Workbook;

    //Make sure file is not empty
    if(wkbk != null)
    {
        if(wkbk.Worksheets.Count > 0)
        {
            //Get the first worksheet
            ExcelWorksheet curworksheet = wkbk.Worksheets.First();

            //Get row count
            var row = curworksheet.Dimension.End.Row;
            //Get column count
            var col = curworksheet.Dimension.End.Column;

            //Cycle through rows
            foreach(int i = 2; i <= row; i++)
            {
                //Cycle through columns for current row
                foreach(int = 1; i <= col; i++)
                {
                    //for each col do something...
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: referring to the Cycle rows/columns part, that was my initial thought as well. I am able to open the excel and what not (although with a different method), so I tried cycling through the rows and then fetching the columns at a specific row (as seen above), but i was unsuccessful. i fetch the rows/columns a differnt way using                                                                        int rowcount = range.Rows.Count;
            int columncount = range.Columns.Count;

Comment: @jw.cana1an Have you tried getting the sheet's used range ('Sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count') like **Lee** suggested? Out of curiosity what package are you using to read your excel files?